# обработка try...catch не правильно работает

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, try-catch

Начала пет-проект на nuxt. С axios не могу разобраться.

внутри methods

```js
    async login() {
          try {
            const data = await this.$store.dispatch('login', { email: this.email.toLowerCase(), password: this.password})
            this.$router.push('/admin/user')
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('>>', e)
          }
        }
```

внутри actions, метод login

```js
    async login({ commit }, user) {
        try {
          const resp = await this.$axios.$post('api/login/', user)
          commit('setToken', true)
          console.log('resp')
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('error', e.response)
          return(e)
        }
      }
```

При правильном вводе данных приходит такая ошибка error ReferenceError: axios is not defined.

Comment: axios вы точно  установили?

Comment: да, я его сразу установила когда создавала проект. В модулях он есть

Answer (score 0):

по шагам это в `nuxt.config.js`:

**Шаг 1 - проверяем что добавлен в модуль**

```
 modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios'
]
```

**Шаг 2 - добавляем**
если нужны настройки

```
axios: {}
```

далее на странице: внимание на этот момент - передаем контекст `asyncData({$axios})`

**Шаг 3 - добавляем**

```
async asyncData({$axios}) {
try {
  const test = await $axios.$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  console.log(test)
}
catch (e){
  console.log(e)
}
}
```